# <Function> is not a function, typescript even though it is a function

Tags: typescript, function, arrow-functions

This is what my code looks like

CheckForFunctionality.ts

```
import {customFunctionA, customFunctionB} from './utilFunctions.ts'

// both customFunctionA and customFunctionB are defined as arrow functions
const newFunctionNameA : Function= customFunctionA; 
const newFunctionNameB : Function= customFunctionB;

export const checkFunctionality = () => {
    ....
    ....
    const result = newFunctionNameA() || newFunctionNameB()
    ....

}
```

The unit test case for that file, CheckForFunctionality.test.ts , works and all test pass

but after I make
UseThatFunctionality.ts

```
import {checkFunctionality} from './CheckForFunctionality'


const foo = () => {

    const result = checkFunctionality()
    ....

}
```

my automatic test cases break, with the errors:

- newFunctionNameA is not a function
- newFunctionNameB is not a function

so if I use customFunctionA instead of customFunctionB, it starts working again

My question is why is it breaking when I add UseThatFunctionality and not in CheckForFunctionality.test.ts

Comment: It breaks because you are importing "checkFunctionality" function from the "CheckForFunctionality" which relies on - newFunctionNameA and newFunctionNameB.
To make it work- you can try changing "newFunctionNameA" and"newFunctionNameB" from "function" type to "()=>any".
Something like: const newFunctionNameA : () => any =  customFunctionA; 
Please check. Thanks.

Comment: *"The unit test case for that file, CheckForFunctionality.test.ts , works and all test pass"* That's fairly surprising, given that you're declaring `newFunctionNameA` but using `newFunctionA` (missing `Name`) (and the same for `B`). Does the test not try calling the function?? So it looks like a typo, or alternatively perhaps you over-edited the code to put it in the question. Please double-check for typos in the original code. If it's typos, just delete the question. if not, please make sure you post a **reproducible** minimal example, more: [mre]

Comment: Side note: There's no reason for the `: Function` type annotation on your new constants, just do the assignment without a type annotation and the correct function type will be inferred. (But there's no reason for those constants in what you've shown. Just have `checkFunctionality` call `customFunctionA` and `customFunctionB` directly.)

Comment: @HarishDalmia, i tried what you said and unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, there are no typos in the original code but yes there was a typo when i was writing the question, I didnt copy paste the code, because i wanted it to be a bit more readable, just changed the variablenames. I fixed the typos now

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typos. Too bad that wasn't the problem. :-) *"The unit test case for that file, CheckForFunctionality.test.ts , works and all test pass"* Do those tests call the function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it does
to be more precise, the it tests a method of a class, and that method calls the function

expect(MyClass.method(....)).toEqual(expectedResult)

Comment: I'm sorry, the information here is just too fragmentary for us to be able to help. Assigning the imported functions to local constants isn't going to cause any problem (but again: it's also unnecessary). Beyond that, without (again) an [mre], I'm afraid we can't help.